# NextJS Image Error - React.jsx: type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ecmascript-6

I recently updated my app to enforce ES6 by adding "type:module" to my package.json. In addition, I changed the following to accommodate this change.

next.config.js -> next.config.cjs

tailwind.config.js -> tailwind.config.cjs

postcss.config.js -> postcss.config.cjs

The problem is since doing so, I get the following error on all of my Image components :

> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component  from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Example of the Image component I'm using to render

```
  <Image
      src="/next.svg"
      fill
      style={{
        objectFit: "contain",
      }}
      alt="Your Company"
   />
```

It's imported like `import Image from "next/image";`

If I remove all of the Image components from my app, it will load fine. It's important to note I never had an issue before enforcing ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was an issue with the NextJS Image component. Currently, it seems like the Image component does not support ES Modules. As a result, I was getting the above error.

Instead of importing it like `import Image from "next/image";` import it as

```
import ImageModule from 'next/image';
const Image = ImageModule.default;
```

You can find more detail on this issue at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54777

Answer (score 0):

The error or warning you encountered is typically related to mistakes in import/export, such as using an incorrect path or using a variable as a JSX component. Ensure that you use the correct path and follow proper import/export conventions to avoid this issue.

***( Check Your Image Component Is this Component Import/export Correct? Read all this and simply use Image Component )***

**1. Mixing up default and named imports and exports:-**

When we export default, mean only one component export then use `import simple_component` name. If export component_named then `import {Component_named}`

**Example :-**

**Header.js**

```
export default function Header() {
  return <h2>Hello world</h2>;
}
```

**App.js**

```
 import Header from './Header';
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

**2. Declared a variable with JSX code instead of a function**

The below code will throw the error.

```
function App() {
    // This line throws error: 
    // Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
    // or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    const Message = <label>Hello world!</label>;
    return (
        <div>
            <Message/>      
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

However, the Message variable cannot be used as a component unless it is not a function. React components should be a function or class that returns HTML. To solve the error, change the Message variable to a function that returns JSX code as given below.

```
function App() {
    const Message = () => <label>Hello world!</label>;
    return (
        <div>
            <Message/>      
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue wasn't with any of my components, but NextJS's Image component. See my answer below for the solution.